# conda activate env not working on azure batch node task

Tags: pip, anaconda

I am using [linux-datascience-svm](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.linux-data-science-vm) VM provided on Azure in my batch GPU pool. At first I tried to pip install some libraries like so:

```
pip install --upgrade pip;
pip install docopt;
pip install pubnub;
pip install azure;
pip install glob2;
pip install theano>=0.8.2
pip freeze;
```

However when my application tries to import theano it gives a `Module Not Found error` for theano.

I tried leveraging Anaconda so I tried activating `base` environment in the pool start task, then running the following task cmdline:

```
/bin/bash -c "set -e;
source activate base;wait"
```

however I get the following error:

`/bin/bash: line 1: activate: No such file or directory`

I tried to put the conda environment activation statement in a bash script and running it but I get this error:

`./run.sh: line 3: source: activate: file not found`

How can I access my installed libraries like theano after they've been installed on the pool in conda or in the general environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing activate with the absolute path to the activate script in conda. It would look something like

```
source /data/username/miniconda2/bin/activate base
```